# Ruby dynamic arguments in dynamically created methods

Tags: ruby, dynamic, metaprogramming, dynamic-programming

I have the following kind of method definition:

```ruby
method_name = :foo
method_arguments = [:bar, :baz]
method_mandatory_arguments = {:quux => true}
method_body = ->{ quux ? bar + baz : bar - baz }
```

So I want to get a real method. But [define_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method) has no any possibility to define method arguments dynamically. I know another way to use [class_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) but I know than defining methods with [class_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) is much slower than [define_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method).
How I can effectively archive this?

I did some benchmarks in rails console:

```
class Foo; end
n = 100_000

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('define_method') do
    n.times { |i| Foo.send(:define_method, "method1#{i}", Proc.new { |a, b, c| a + b + c }) }
  end
  x.report('class_eval') do
    n.times { |i| Foo.class_eval %Q{ def method2#{i}(a, b, c); a + b + c; end } }
  end
end
```

So I've got the following results:

```
                user       system     total      real
define_method  0.750000   0.040000   0.790000 (  0.782988)
class_eval     9.510000   0.070000   9.580000 (  9.580577)
```

Comment: `class_eval` makes sense to me.  Is performance really an issue here?  It's hard to imagine a use case where it would be.

Comment: You could have your define_method block accept varargs, then interpret the args array based on your argument meta data captured in the closure.

Comment: @dbenhur, ok but in this case in fact I have one method that implements multiply behaviour so I must implement basic argument behaviour by hand (argument presence, default arguments etc). This is what i trying to avoid.

Comment: Are you sure class_eval is slower for this sort of stuff? My recollection was that because define_method creates a closure it can be slower (or cause leaks)

Comment: @FrederickCheung, you can see benchmarks in upper. In my case I have the module with ~500 methods which defined dynamically, so I am lose a lot of load time in case of class_eval. In any case I am most interested in alternative solutions.

Comment: Ah, I can see that. I was thinking about invocation performance.

Comment: Can you show us your implementation using class_eval given that method_body is a lambda with no parameters?

Comment: @SemyonPerepelitsa There is only **define_method** implementation but I want more flexibility so now I'm looking for other ways and **class_eval** is the worse.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple way to implement what you are asking using either class_eval or define_method. Since method_body is a lambda it can only access local variables defined right before it.

```
method_body = ->{ quux ? bar + baz : bar - baz }
quux = true
method_body.call # undefined local variable or method ‘quux’

quux = true
method_body = ->{ quux ? bar + baz : bar - baz }
method_body.call # undefined local variable or method ‘bar’
```

I would suggest you to revise your requirements. If your method body should be a lambda, define all arguments for it. Then this is a natural fit for define_method:

```
method_body = ->(quux, bar = 0, baz = 0){ quux ? bar + baz : bar - baz }
define_method(method_name, &method_body)
```

If your method body can be a string, eval is the only option:

```
method_body = "quux ? bar + baz : bar - baz"
eval <<RUBY
def #{method_name} #{arguments}
  #{method_body}
end
RUBY
```

Comment: From your point of view I want to create a proc (or lambda that doesn't matter in my case) with the set of arguments that I store in a specific form.
So I have an array ```method_arguments = [:bar, :baz]``` and I want to use it like this: ```method_body = ->(*method_arguments){ quux ? bar + baz : bar - baz }```

Comment: This is not possible with procs/lambdas. Can you store your method body as a string? It would help if you give a more specific real-world example.

Comment: It seems that the only way is to use class_eval.